# Pagination implementation not working on my React app

Tags: reactjs

I am building a movie app using react and IMDB Api. But I am difficulty getting my pagination to fetch different data per page. Right now each of the page displays same data.
The Api Renders 100 movie data but I want it to be 50 per page.

This is my code so far.

**Trending.js**

```
const Trending = () => {
  const [movieTrends, setMovieTrends] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTrends = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `https://imdb-api.com/en/API/MostPopularMovies/${process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIEAPI_KEY}/?page=${page}`
        );

        console.log(data);
        setMovieTrends(data?.items);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchTrends();
  }, [page]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loading />
      ) : (
        <div className="trending">
          {movieTrends &&
            movieTrends
              .map((trend) => (
                <MovieGrid
                  key={trend?.id}
                  id={trend?.id}
                  image={trend?.image}
                  title={trend?.title}
                  year={trend?.year}
                  rating={trend?.imDbRating}
                />
              ))}
        </div>
      )}
      <AppPagination setPage={setPage} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Pagination.js**

```
`const AppPagination = ({ setPage, numOfPages = 10 }) => {
  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setPage(page);
    window.scroll(0, 0);
  };
  return (
    <div className="page_container">
      <div className="root">
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
          <Pagination
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            count={numOfPages}
            onChange={(e) => handlePageChange(e.target.textContent)}
          />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AppPagination;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
movieTrends.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize).map(() => {
    // your code goes here
 }
)
```

You need to slice the records from the array that you want to show.